# orthogonality of matrices

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices

A theorem in linear Algebra tells us

> A matrix **U** is orthogonal iff **$U^TU=I$** where **I** is the identity matrix.

I get the part that if **U** is orthogonal then $U^TU=I$, but why should **$U^T$** also be orthogonal, consider the following case:
Let $$U =\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\c&d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

let $$ a_1= \begin{bmatrix} a\\c \end{bmatrix} \ and\ a_2= \begin{bmatrix} b\\d \end{bmatrix}$$

we have,
$$a_1.a_2=0,\ |a_1|=1 \ and\ |a_2|=1$$
  i.e. from the theorem
 $$a^2+b^2=1,\ c^2+d^2=1,\ ac+bd=0 \ \ \ \ \ -> case1$$

Now, the real confusion is **[this site](https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/prove-that-the-transpose-of-an-orthogonal-matrix-is-an-orthogonal-matrix/#)** gives proof then $U^T$ is also orthogonal, but for that to happen this should hold true:
 $$a^2+c^2=1,\ b^2+d^2=1,\ ab+cd=0\ \ \ \ \ ->case2$$
I don't see how is this possible in general cases where $U$ is an orthogonal matrix. How is $U^T$ orthongonal and how can both **case1** and **case2** hold at the same time in every case where $U$ is an orthogonal matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the set of equalities in case 1 holds. We can write $a=\sin x,b=\cos x,c=\cos y,d=\pm\sin y$ for some angles $x$ and $y$, by the Pythagorean trigonometric identity (the sign in front of $d$ is important, and differentiates rotation and reflection matrices). Then $ac+bd=0$ is $\sin x\cos y\pm\cos x\sin y=\sin(x\pm y)=0$, so $x=-y$ or $x=y$ up to periodicity (modulo $2\pi$) if the sign in front of $d$ was $+$ or $-$ respectively. Hence
$$a^2+c^2=\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$$
$$b^2+d^2=\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$$
$$ab+cd=\sin x\cos x-\cos x\sin x=0$$
and case 2 holds. A similar argument proves case 1 from case 2, so $U$ and $U^T$ are both orthogonal.

Comment: Except that the transpose of a product is the product of the transposes **taken in the reverse order**.

Comment: Your proof still makes absolutely no sense to me, so the comment remains.

Comment: @user5713492 Isn't it just a property of the inverse function? $AB=I\iff BA=I$

Comment: Right, but that's already @SiongThyeGoh's answer.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel , this proof is already given in the link in my question, but there is a need to look into the matrix. Instead of proving it this way, can you please try to prove why would $a^2+c^2=1$? I have been trying it but i have no clue to begin, and proving it this way seems like we're using the theorem to prove itself

Comment: @juztcode Done.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel , why do you take d=+-Siny and not just positive like in other variables?

Comment: @juztcode These lead to two different classes of $2×2$ orthogonal matrices. One preserves orientation and one reverses it.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel , what about a? Why not also put a +- infront of it?

Comment: @juztcode $a$ can always be made positive after all signs have been assigned, just by negating all variables.

Comment: This proof should be in every high schooler's textbooks. Thanks mate. :-)

Answer (score 1):

$U$ is a square matrix.

$U^TU=I$ means $U^T$ is the inverse of $U$, hence we have $UU^T=I$.